# Amount compare in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a two amount suppose Principal amount and collection Fees and I want to show alert if collection fee is above the 50% of Principal Amount in JavaScript.

How do I do this in JavaScript?  I have the following

```
var PrinCurr    = $('input#ndprincipal').val(); 
var CollFeeCurr = $('input#ndcollfee').val(); 

if(CollFeeCurr >= PrinCurr)                     
{
    alert("'Collection Fee' is greater than 50% of the 'Principal Amount Due'");
    return false;                       
}
```

Comment: hi! what have you tried?

Comment: `var PrinCurr = $('input#ndprincipal').val(); var CollFeeCurr = $('input#ndcollfee').val(); if(CollFeeCurr >= PrinCurr)
     {
      alert("'Collection Fee' is greater than 50% of the 'Principal Amount Due'");
      return false;
     }`

Comment: added that to the question for you :)

Comment: What your approach misses is the "math". Your if condition does a simple comparison and triggers once the fees are **bigger or equal to** the principal amount. 

What you wanna do however, is to check if the fees are bigger than 50 **percent** of the principal amount. Therefore you need to employ   the calculation of percentage.

You can check out more in-depth info on calculating percentages here: http://www.helpingwithmath.com/by_subject/percentages/per_calculating.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
if (fee > 0.5*principal)
  alert('RAWR');
```

**Edit:** To fix the code you have posted you just need to update the condition `CollFeeCurr >= PrinCurr`.

You are comparing to the `PrinCurr` itself, rather than to 50% of it. Update your condition to:

```
CollFeeCurr >= 0.5*PrinCurr
```

Comment: @YTowOnt9 this doesn't work for me, don't know why this is happen?

Comment: if(CollFeeCurr > (0.5*PrinCurr))
     {
      alert("'Collection Fee' is greater than 50% of the 'Principal Amount Due'");
      return false;
     }

Comment: @AyanB Yes. That is better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if I do it should be relatively simple:

```
var principal_amt;
var coll_fees;

// initialize them

if(coll_fees > principal_amt * 0,5)
{
    alert("'tis bigger");
}
```

edit: someone was faster

Comment: 2 people were faster.  :)

Comment: They indeed *are* originally strings: `$('..').val(); ` (however my comment was still wrong and the saving grace is str*num -> num). Also, there is a typo `0,5` (which is valid syntax thanks to the comma-operator but makes this not work at all).

Comment: I see what you mean now. The OP posted this later than our answers though and our examples employ numeric values / non initialized objects

Answer (score 1):

You do math.
Assuming the following:

Principle = 100
Collection fees are a total of 51

```
var Princ = 100;
var CFees = 51;
var percCFees = CFees / Princ // =.51

if (percCFees > .50) {
alert("Collection fees are more than 50% of the principle of $"+ Princ +".");
}
```